# UITabBarController Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create something like below.
RootView does not have TabBar, From the second view there should be TabBar.

[image]

What I have currently done is, I am using `UINavigationController` as controller calass

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   
    
    UIViewController *rootController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But how can I use `UITabBar` with tabBarController from SecondViewController?

Answer (score 1):

create the objects of the second view and then push your view with the tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

From Storyboard embed your SecondViewController in TabBar. Select your controller and go to Editor -> Embed in -> TabBar Controller! I'm from my mobile..sorry if i have any mispells!

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your Tabbar controller's object. Initialize your tab bar controller's object and add all other controller objects to the tabbar controller's viewcontroller array.

On button action:-

1> Initialize tab bar controller and suppose you name its object as objTab;

2> objTab.viewcontrollers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..] ---> Objects of all viewcontrollers that are a part of your tab bar controller. Thus all objects need to be created first.

3> self.navigationcontroller pushViewController: objTAb

Answer (score 0):

use this type of method in `AppDelegate.m` and property-synthesize `UITabBarController` and store array of viewcontroller in it also in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method just assign navigationViewController as a RootViewController like bellow..

```
RootViewController *masterViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
```

after then when you want to add TabBar to any view at that time call this bellow method like this..

```
[appDelegate addTabBarControllerInwindow];

-(void)addTabBarControllerInwindow 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];
    
    [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];//tabBarController.view
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick (not using ARC):

```
//vc1, vc2, vc3 = your view controllers
NSArray *viewControllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,vc3, nil];    
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllersArray];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
[tabBarController release];
```

What you want to do is create the UITabBarController and push that along the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

For Sample Write loadnewview method at appdelegate .Use buttonPressed method for button action or  any object action of first view controller as shown below to display tab bar from second view controller.
I have taken two tabs for sample so I wrote Capacity as 2. You can take up to 5.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{    
    HomeViewController *homeVC=[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];        
    [appDelegate loadnewview];
}    

-(void)loadnewview
{    
    if(!self.tabBarController)
        self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;    
    NSMutableArray *localcontrollerarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];        
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];        
    UINavigationController *navi1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];        
    [localcontrollerarray addObject:navi1];        
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[ScanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScanViewController" bundle:nil];    
    UINavigationController *navi2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];        
    [localcontrollerarray addObject:navi2];        
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = localcontrollerarray;    
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an Application using Tab Bar Controller and on the ViewDidLoad method of the view controller for which you want to hide the tab bar use code:

```
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

And don't forget to unhide the tab bar using the same code replacing NO instead of YES for the view controller for which you want to show the tab bar.

Comment: -1. Unnecessarily changing the root view controller to being a UITabBarController.