# Best practice when combining Tabs with Navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I used *tabbed application template* to start my new iPhone project.
I will have 4 tabs.
And I want to nave navigation bar at the top.
So I added this in **AppDelegate**:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationcontroller, viewController2, nil];
```

And this added navigation bar only at the top of the first ViewController (first tab).
What I want is to add navigation bar for the whole application not just in one view.
This will enable me to jump from one view to another and back across tabs.
So what is the best way to programmatically make one navigation bar for all tab views?
**UPDATE**
Basically my main question is should I have **one navigation bar for all views** or **each tab should have its own navigation bar**?
What is best practice in "iDevelopers" world.

Comment: You might be melding your design patterns/workflows too much. With the tab bar, each tab is essentially its own navigation stack (provided each tab has its own navigation).

If you want the navigation to be on the "outside", I would think you would have to add the tab bar controller to a navigation controller. Personally I havent done this myself, but I know adding a nav controller to just one of the tabs only gives you a navigation stack on that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather have the self.window.rootViewController be a navigationController, and afterwards, just push your tabBarController or

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// create someViewController
[viewControllers addObject:someView];
// create someViewController2
[viewControllers addObject:someView2];


UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabController]
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work when I switch tabs it doesn't show back button.

Comment: It should be any back buttons to switch between tabs. There already are tabs you can tap on, the back button should only pop viewcontroller that are in a tab hierarchy. If you really want this feature, just make a navigationcontroller with a bottom bar with 3 buttons that push viewcontrollers on the same navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have navigation bars on each controller, you should to have `UINavigationController` on each tab of your `UITabBarController`
Look an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227181/custom-uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller/15227728#15227728) question.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have one navigation bar for all. I don't know if this is smart idea that's why I ask. Example: user click on tab 2 and click on some button that goes to tab 4 and from there to tab 3. Now he will have back on the nav bar and can go back to tab 4 and then back to tab 2. I find some workaround (add tab bar on each view with nav bar as a root view) but I don't know if this is the right way to do this or I should stick with nav vontroller per tab.

Answer (score 0):

You you need navigation bar you have to add UINavigationController as you did for each view controller in tab bar. So self.tabBarController.viewControllers will have all navigation controllers.

Its not good idea to switch across tabs without user intervention.