# uitabbarcontroller not showing on other uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app has a first page containing a `UITabBarController` and `tabBar`.
But when I `pushViewController` to `UINavigationController` , my `UITabBarController` is not showing.

appdelegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
anasayfaViewController * firstTab= [[anasayfaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anasayfaViewController" bundle:nil];
SehirRehberiViewController *sehirRehberi = [[SehirRehberiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SehirRehberiViewController" bundle:nil];
duyuruViewController *duyuru = [[duyuruViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"duyuruViewController" bundle:nil];
sikayetViewController *sikayet = [[sikayetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sikayetViewController" bundle:nil];
digerViewController *diger = [[digerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"digerViewController" bundle:nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstTab,sehirRehberi,duyuru,sikayet,diger];
        navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
// [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

firstTab viewcontroller have button and click events:

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:haberler animated:NO];
}
```

when I click `UIViewController` it is opening, but not showing `UITabBarController`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you wanting a navigation controller within your tab bar controller? You have it the other way around at the moment so the new view is pushed over the tab bar

Comment: @Leta0n haberler is uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You have `UITabBarController` as rootViewController of your `UINavigationController`. And `UINavigationController` as root Controller of your app. Instead of that you have to set `UITabBarController` as root Controller of your App and add `UINavigationController` in each tab.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227181/custom-uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller/15227728#15227728) answer.

Comment: thank you for answer Valantin . But when I click to button ,where I can pushViewController ? so which navigationController ?

Comment: You push new controller from navigationController which is inside one of your tabs.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you need to create Array of Your All view-controller(Navigation Controller) like

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController2,navigationController1,navigationController3,nil];
```

and

you need to set Winodw's `Rootviewcontroller` is
 `[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];`  not a Navigationcontroller

As par you Code example:-

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

anasayfaViewController * firstTab= [[anasayfaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anasayfaViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

SehirRehberiViewController *sehirRehberi = [[SehirRehberiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SehirRehberiViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sehirRehberi];

duyuruViewController *duyuru = [[duyuruViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"duyuruViewController" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:duyuru];

sikayetViewController *sikayet = [[sikayetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sikayetViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sikayet];

digerViewController *diger = [[digerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"digerViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:diger];


self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];

 [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

**UPDATE:-**

If you want to `TabbarController` adding at button Click for NextViewcontroller then you can do with something different way like Bellow :-

For example you have **loginScreen** while app lonch and it `login` button click you need to push a view-controller and that View-controller contain those Tabbar.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    LoginViewcontroller *objLogin = [[LoginViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];


     self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
```

In loginViewcontroller LoginButton action:-

```
-(IBAction)LoginSuccess
{

    anasayfaViewController * firstTab= [[anasayfaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anasayfaViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

    SehirRehberiViewController *sehirRehberi = [[SehirRehberiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SehirRehberiViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sehirRehberi];

    duyuruViewController *duyuru = [[duyuruViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"duyuruViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    UINavigationController *navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:duyuru];

    sikayetViewController *sikayet = [[sikayetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sikayetViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sikayet];

    digerViewController *diger = [[digerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"digerViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:diger];


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: @Erhan Demirci check now there i puting both method from app lonch tabbarcontroller and button click Tabbar controller hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using my following snippet

```
anasayfaViewController * firstTab= [[anasayfaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anasayfaViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

    SehirRehberiViewController *sehirRehberi = [[SehirRehberiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SehirRehberiViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sehirRehberi];

// object for tabbarviewcontroller
self.tab.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNav,secondNav,nil];
```

I've shown you the sample for two tabs inside tabbarcontroller. You can customise it as per your need.

Enjoy Programming!